# Не инициализируются свойство fetchedResultController

Tags: swift

Использую NSFetchedResultsController для сортировки .Но не инициализируются свойство fetchedResultController
[image: Ошибка инициализации свойства]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSFetchedResultsController использует дженерик, поэтому нужно явно указать результат его работы (`class NSFetchedResultsController<ResultType> : NSObject where ResultType : NSFetchRequestResult`), что вы хотите получить. Попробуйте так:

```
var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Customer> = {
...
}()
```